# How to change dialog background color in tabcontrol?

Tags: windows, mfc, background-color, tabcontrol

```
BOOL CTabControlDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(rect);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    return CDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
}
```

CTabControlDlg is dialog in the tabcontrol.

Comment: And what is the issue?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't provide much informations, I assume you're talking about MFC. This should do the trick:

```
BOOL CTabControlDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
   CRect rect;
   GetClientRect(rect);

   pDC->SetBkColor(m_clrBkClr);
   pDC->FillRect(&rect, &m_brsBkGnd);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Windows Forms is .NET. Neither the question, nor your proposed answer are.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes you're right thank you. The code is using MFC. Nevertheless the answer is right.

Comment: The answer may or may not be right. That totally depends on what the OP's issue is. They haven't disclosed that yet.